# Является ли локальная переменная конструктора свойством объекта?

Tags: javascript

Является ли локальная переменная объявленная в функции-конструкторе вида:

```
function Func () {
    let a = 5;
}
```

свойством ново созданного объекта, разумеется глобально эта переменная не доступна, но вопрос именно, является ли эта переменная свойством или просто локальной переменной объекта?

```
let obj = new Func();
```

Update:

```
function Func () {
    let obj = {
        '+': function(k) {
            return k + 1;
        }
    }

    this.read = function () {
        let i = 1; 
        let a = '+'
        return obj[a](i);
    }
}

let obj = new Func();

obj.read();
```

Раз объект совершенно ничего не знает про локальную переменную функции-конструктора, то как он понимает при вызове метода read, что нужно выполнить ту функцию из локальной переменной-ссылки на объект obj?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Локальная переменная не является свойством. Никогда. Не в JS.

Это просто локальная переменная в функции, доступ к которой можно получить через замыкания. С объектом она совершенно никак не связана.

---

#### Ответы на комментарий

> Конструктор и созданный с помощью него объект хранятся в памяти

независимо друг от друга (ну, не совсем так, но не будем мудрить)

> вместе со своими свойствами, методами и локальными переменными.

локальные переменные есть только у функции. в данном случае у конструктора. они свои на каждый вызов функции

> Сам объект не имеет доступа к локальной переменной конструктора на прямую

да

> но метод объекта(read) через замыкание

абсолютно неважно, является ли он методом объекта или нет. это просто функция, которая имеет доступ к внешнему для неё скоупу через замыкание

> (read) через замыкание может обращаться к этой локальной переменной

да

> которая все еще находится в памяти

да. и она проживёт не меньше, чем проживёт функция read

> как только объект уничтожится(если не будет ссылки ни одной на него)

он не обязан уничтожиться сразу

> то и конструктора больше не будет

на конструктор могут быть другие ссылки, а у тебя он вообще глобальный

> и локальной переменной тоже

локальная переменная является результатом конкретного вызова функции и не принадлежит конструктору самому по себе
она уничтожится, когда кончатся ссылки на неё (через замыкания)
и то не так, потому что формально схема замыканий удерживает весь скоуп пока хотя бы одна из его переменных нужна
но ни один нормальный браузер так беспричинно не поступает уже давно

Comment: @Qwertiy Конструктор и созданный с помощью него объект хранятся в памяти вместе со своими свойствами, методами и локальными переменными. Сам объект не имеет доступа к локальной переменной конструктора на прямую, но метод объекта(```read```) через замыкание может обращаться к этой локальной переменной, которая все еще находится в памяти, как только объект уничтожится(если не будет ссылки ни одной на него), то и конструктора больше не будет и локальной переменной тоже, так?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69695/discussion-on-answer-by-qwertiy------).